# Should we make a "unsure" tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Occasionally, although not often, there's a question where I can't figure out how to tag it. Usually I'll make one that fits, but low-rep users might not be able to do this.

So, should we make a "unsure" tag, which will allow users to properly tag it with an edit?

Answer (score 3):

One can always edit the tags in a later moment, the only limit being the maximum of five tags which can be applied to a question.

And honestly, while I can understand how a question on certain SE communities must take time pressure and urgency into account (for example if I need to finish a script by the end of the work day, I will rush to post the question on Stackoverflow), I have yet to see a worldbuilding question which cannot wait a few hours for the OP to make up their mind on the tags/phrasing to use.

About the "unsure" tag, a tag serves to define the content of a question. Think of it as a label. One can be an expert in a certain tag, for example "physics", "magic", etc. What can an expert in "unsure" be relied upon?